# Can I setup an SVN server on Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, development, svn

I have an SVN server which I use for my personal web development projects. Can I move this to Ubuntu One? Will it be accessible over the intenet? Would I be able to perform the normal SVN operations like `commit` and `update`?

Comment: If you already have a SVN server running then why would you sync the repositories with U1?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe he's asking if using U1 as a backup service for his SVN server would cause any problems.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you can't use SVN with Ubuntu One like you would use the SVN server.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

At some point we thought of adding a WebDAV backend to the file sync service, and that would be a step towards being able to do svn, but it never got much traction.

> Ubuntu One is not a backup service, so if you were wanting to use it for that, please disabuse yourself of the notion; there are many things that make up a good backup service, and we provide none of them, and we probably never will. People are building a backup service *on top of* ours, namely the deja-dup guys are doing that and that's awesome, but that's something else.

Why not use [launchpad](http://launchpad.net)?